# Channel Field Group gone

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, database, field-group

I have an odd one where it appears that 1 of my custom field groups has disappeared. I don;t when, there is no backup (even if there was I can't tell wether it disappeared yesterday or last year). It was a simple one Matrix field with multiple columns.

There is no mention of it in exp_field_groups in the DB AND the actual entry that was using this custom field is still displaying on the front end. It has reverted to using another field groups ID in the DB and CP. Editing the sole entry causes errors and all file uploads that where populated are no longer present in the backend but are on the front end.

As the actual field group is missing, I tried to recreate it, yet, because the fields I'm trying to re-create already exist in the matrix area of the DB, I get errors about field name in use, obviously.

I've stumbled around phpMyAdmin trying to backwards engineer a new field_group and alter some references to it in the Matrix DB columns to no luck as I just don't know what to change and where.

My question is if ALL matrix data is present in the database, how can I create a new field_group and assign this group to the existing entry and save the information ?

Anyone have anything ?